# unable to get the subject/Title value from the meeting to taskpane in outlook addin js

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

[image: in the image i pointed, i want to fetch the meet Title in taskpane]

here is the code I have tried but its though the error
**Function addHandlerAsync has invalid parameters.**

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.ItemChanged, function (result: any){
  console.log("subject",result)
  const items = Office.context.mailbox.item;
  items.subject.getAsync(function(result){
    console.log("subject",result)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ItemChange` event is fired when a different Outlook item is selected for viewing while the task pane is pinned, not when an item is changed.

You can post or vote for an existing feature request on [Tech Community](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions) where they are considered when the Office dev team goes through the planning process.

Comment: thanks for your response, so is there any other way to get the title in task pane or its not possible for now?

Comment: See [Get or set the subject when composing an appointment or message in Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/get-or-set-the-subject)

Comment: Hi @eugeneastafiev I have used the code link you provided, and now I am able to get the subject from the meeting but it causes infinite rendering how can I stop it?

Comment: I'd suggest posting separate questions in new threads, so users could recognize questions and answers easily.

Comment: okay will do it